# Delay in Unregistering Geofences

Tags: android, google-api-client, geofencing, android-geofence

So I tried Geofencing in my app. I was able to trigger successfully my app to send a notification if my phone has entered into a Geofence. However, I noticed that even if I unregistered the Geofence already, the app takes like around 3mins at least to unregister. I was able to verify this by unregistering the Geofence via a Checkbox and closing the app. The app still notifies me that I have entered a Geofence even when it has already been unregistered.

It was only after a specific amount of time that the system finally stops notifying me that I entered a geofence. So it seems unregistering takes some times.. Has anyone noticed this? Any reasons why?

here is my code snippet to unregister. The log in my app says I was successfully able to unregister.

```
try {
    LocationServices
        .getGeofencingClient(mContext)
        .removeGeofences(getGeofencePendingIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Geofences unregistered");
            }
    });
} catch (SecurityException securityException) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Security Exception Error, Geofences not Unregistered. "
        + securityException.toString());
}
```